# Find all regex matches

Tags: javascript, regex

Everyone tells me that if I have a regex like `/blah/g` and I repeatedly `exec` it on a string, I'll go through all the matches until I'm at the end.

But what if my regex is `/^$/g` and my string is `""`? THEN WHAT?

This works fine:

```
var re = /bar/g,
    str = "foobarfoobar";
while ((match = re.exec(str)) != null) {
    alert("match found at " + match.index);
}
```

This goes into an infinite loop !

```
var re = /^$/g,
    str = "";
while ((match = re.exec(str)) != null) {
    alert("match found at " + match.index);
}
```

Why, Javascript? Why?

(And more importantly, how on earth am I supposed to iterate through matches of a regex if my regex contains `^$` and my string could possibly be the empty string???)

Comment: Witout the `/m` modifier, the `/^$/g` regex makes little sense since `/g` search for multiple matches, but there can only be one.

Comment: do you need to support any user-generated regex or just a special case of `^$` for which it doesn't make sense to iterate over anything?

Comment: Since you don't have capture groups, you don't need `while` `exec`. You can use `match`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it's actually part of a larger regex e.g. `/blah|foo|^$/g` which I would generally apply multiple times.

Comment: Why are you looking for empty space in an empty space.  If a user inputs an empty string you should trap this BEFORE doing any pattern matching, all serious web-forms catch or trap stupid or malicous input.

Comment: @ArifBurhan I have split a long input into lines and I am matching line by line. (Sheesh! Ask one simple question and 99 people question what you're thinking...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is caused by the fact that JS regex engine does not advance its index when matching an empty string. You can move it "manually" with some additional code (taken from regex101.com sample code generator page):

```js
var re = /^$/g; 
var str = '';
if ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {  // Here you manually advance
        re.lastIndex++;              // the index
    }
    alert(m[0]);
}
```

Comment: Ah, okay. Ugh, I still feel like all that code I've seen is broken now. I'll accept when the timer is up.